# How to make custom CallBack button with void function in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to make a callback function with void function (()->()). But i still figure it how the actually void function work. There are two ViewController which one of them gonna used as bottomSheet in other controller. And I want to add callback Function when the bottomSheetInfo show up. Here's the code of bottom Sheet :

ViewController as Bottom Sheet Info
`

```
import UIKit

class InfoSheeetViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tittleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconView: UIImageView!
    
    var pageFrom: ScreenOrigin?
    var callbackActionPressed : (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func handleButtonActionPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.callbackActionPressed?()
    }
```

`

What must I do with another ViewController to make void function work ?. And if you don't mind, can you explain me how actually void function work in swift? Thank you so much

Comment: `myController.callbackActionPressed = { print("hello, world") }` where `myController` is an instance of `InfoSheeetViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simply wanna know when bottom sheet shows up so you just have to call
ur function self.callbackActionPressed?() in viewWillAppear function of sheet view controller

with storyboard

```
    let infoVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? InfoSheeetViewController
    infoVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    infoVC?.callbackActionPressed = {
           print("vc is presented")
    }
    present(infoVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

without story board

```
    let infoVC = InfoSheeetViewController()
    infoVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    infoVC?.callbackActionPressed = {
           print("vc is presented")
    }
    present(infoVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but wait a minute here if you just wanna detect the info shows up you can use built in native completion handler of present function which is

```
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: (() -> Void)?)


    let infoVC = InfoSheeetViewController()
    infoVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(infoVC!, animated: true) {
        print("pop up is shows up")
    }
```